# How to filter response with delay and retries : RxJava

Tags: rx-java, rx-android

Beginner to RxJava, one of the ask is to call a method which is returning observable boolean.  If the method returns true than exit, if false than retry.  It needs to be done multiple times with a logic of delay.  For e.g in every 30 seconds it will retry if value is true.

Here is my observable method

```
@RxLogObservable
    public rx.Observable<Boolean> checkForCatalogDownloadSuccess() {
        return rx.Observable.create(new rx.Observable.OnSubscribe<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Subscriber<? super Boolean> subscriber) {
                try {
                    String catalogDownloadStatus = mSnappyDBManager.getStringFromSnappy(SnappyDBManager.CATALOG_DOWNLOAD_STATUS);
                    CatalogDownloadStatus downloadStatus = CatalogDownloadStatus.valueOf(catalogDownloadStatus);
                    CatalogDownloadResponse catalogDownloadResponse = new CatalogDownloadResponse();

                    if(downloadStatus == CatalogDownloadStatus.SUCCESS ) {
                        subscriber.onNext(true);
                    }
                    else {
                    subscriber.onNext(false);
                    }

                    subscriber.onCompleted();

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Timber.e(ex, null);
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Just a correctness thing: in your catch clause, either call onCompleted or onError.

Comment: Ohh yeah, good catch.

Comment: Since the body of your `call` function is synchronous you do not need to pack it into an observable. If you want to retry if `downloadStatus` is not `SUCCESS` you can use a simple while loop. This is probably not desired, you want some delays between status requests even if the staus is not `SUCCESS`. I guess you just want to poll using 2 different delays. You can achieve this using the `interval` observable.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `Boolean` observable and you want to resubscribe (say 3 times) if `false` or if no message is received for some time (say 5 seconds), then you can use the following statement to achieve this goal:

```
subscription = observable.map(s -> {
            if (!s) {
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }
            return true;
        }).timeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS,scheduler)
                .retry(3)
                .take(1)
                .subscribe(subscriber);
```

Providing a scheduler to timeout is optional, but comes in handy when you want to test your method.

Comment: I tried this and only problem with this is TimeOut is not working as expected.  Have increased the time out to 60 seconds but all the retries happen in few seconds. Here is how the code looks like http://pastebin.com/cxjBtZ12

Comment: The retries before the specified timeout must be due to `false` messages coming out of `checkForCatalogDownloadSuccess()`. You specified `if false then retry` and this is what is happening. If you do not want to retry in this case you can try `observable.timeout(60,TimeUnit.Seconds).filter(s->s).take(1)`.

Comment: Tried that but OnCompleted gets called and retry doesnt happen.   mSubscription = checkForCatalogDownloadSuccess()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .timeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .retry(10)
                .filter(s->s)
                .take(1)
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<Boolean>() {